# Redis-server issue on heroku - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method that crashes with the following error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on XXXX.XXXX.XXX (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)).
```

ON development mode, i just run `redis-server`, then the method execute properly. 
How should I do on Heroku, knowing that there is not such command, and i already have `REDISTOGO_URL` and `REDIS_PROVIDER` in my `Heroku Config Vars`. What else should i do to get this working please?

```
2019-02-04T01:52:30.065122+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Q04lyLoH494OIghgfgdDFPRcQWMzVWnVIhFg0C5jyOIotDHvxLkupSVq6CMORaiisrM84oi8MlQN/kKD8hLGA==", "groupmeeting"=>{"event_type"=>"3", "title"=>"Testing online Sunday 3rd of Feb"}, "commit"=>"Create Event", "locale"=>"en"}
2019-02-04T01:52:30.073016+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e]   User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "2c99733a-4ae0-42f8-97ba-9e4287d7c1cf"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-02-04T01:52:30.082272+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e]    (1.1ms)  BEGIN
2019-02-04T01:52:30.086405+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e]    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
2019-02-04T01:52:30.086668+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
2019-02-04T01:52:30.087969+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e]
2019-02-04T01:52:30.087994+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e] Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
2019-02-04T01:52:30.088018+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e]
2019-02-04T01:52:30.088055+00:00 app[web.1]: [77b20964-3e2b-49b0-b22d-1472d802297e] app/controllers/groupmeetings_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

**initializers/redis_cache.rb**

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "redis_cache.rb")].each {|l| require l }
  end
end
```

**redis_cache.rb**

```
class RedisCache
  def self.new
    Redis.new(Rails.application.config_for(:redis))
  end
end
```

**redis.yml**

```
development:
  <<: redis://localhost:6379
test:
  <<: redis://localhost:6379
production:
  <<: *default
  url: redis://redistogo:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:######/
```

**genfile**

```
gem 'redis'
gem 'hiredis'
....
```

Comment: Did you restarted the application after adding REDISTOGO_URL? Can you post the full stack-trace of the error?

Comment: Heroku apps restart themselves when ENV vars are set or changed

Comment: please provide how you initializing Redis in your application. And what gem you are using for redis connection. If we are talking about redis-rb ("redis" gem) - By default, the client will try to read the ```REDIS_URL``` (or localhost: 6379 on your development).  https://github.com/redis/redis-rb. So ```REDISTOGO_URL``` or ```REDIS_PROVIDER``` will not work without additional initializer.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I just added the error mesage.

Comment: Isn t this the right way to do please?

Comment: So, i am also having an issue with my heroku sidekiq setup. 

Redis::CannotConnectError Sidekiq is the error I'm getting in Sentry.io

Anyone have a solution for this ?